# Output being printed in the same line, Py3k

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In Python 2.x, I'd write...

```
for i in range(5):
    print i,
```

...to get integers from 0 to 4 printed in the same row. How to do that in Python 3.x, since print is a function now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `print(x, end = ' ')`:

From the [release notes](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function):

```
Old: print x,           # Trailing comma suppresses newline  
New: print(x, end=" ")  # Appends a space instead of a newline
```